# My Phone restart automatically in loop without pressing power button?

Tags: recovery-mode, fastboot, reboot

Without pressing power button, my phone restarts again and again. It restarts automatically after showing the asus logo. Since the mobile restart immediately after showing asus logo, I am unable to go into fastboot mode or recovery mode.
Is there anyway I can fix this?
This is happening since 20th April and my 1 year warranty ended on 26th April. Due to lockdown, I am unable to go to service centers as service centers are closed. I am not sure if they will consider my phone warranty period after lockdown.
What should I do?

Comment: May be the power button is permanently pressed (hardware defect)? As pressing the power button for 10 seconds forces a reboot this could explain the permanent reboots.

Comment: The phone also (continuously) reboots when there is an error in the Image / OS configuration.I had to press the power button for about 20 seconds in order to stop my tablet from rebooting.

Comment: Without pressing the power button, phone reboots. It reboots continuously after showing the asus logo every-time. It does not allow me to go into recovery button by pressing combination of buttons for 10+ seconds as it reboots within 5 seconds